# Can I host a HTML site on a server without php and database?

Tags: html

At the moment I am working at a HTML page and I want to host it on a server, so I need a database or php for this?

Comment: If your site doesn't use PHP or a database then obviously you don't need them.

Comment: My site doesn`t need an account to login, so I think I don`t need a database

Answer (score 1):

Just put your file(s) in the correct directory. What's your web server ? If nothing is changed:

- If you use Apache, your html goes in the directory configured in HttpConf as DocumentRoot.
- In case of IIS, put your html in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

You can then access your html in a browser using http://yoururl/yourfile.html

Comment: So, I need a data base if I need to store photos or css/js files?

Comment: No, you won't need any database to host a html file. Your html file will act as a standalone page, with your .css in a styles/ subdirectory, or in the same directory. You can put your pictures in a /Pictures subdirectory, the same way you would open your html  locally, to test it in a browser. Just copy your files to the same paths under the server directory and it will work correctly.

Comment: So I don`t need to learn php and mysql?

Comment: Well, that depends on your school, but for your question above, you won't need to learn all that yet. It will work with only html, css and pictures.. just test it on your PC with IIS or Wamp Server (Apache), you can then access it using **localhost/somehtml.html** in the browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I can use js?

Comment: of course.. your browser runs the <script></script> in your html, and you can include .js files also. Javascript runs on the client side, not on your server.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I will host my html page on school`s server

Answer (score -2):

No, you can use something like `nginx` for that. This is a reverse proxy but it can be used to host a directory.

Comment: Nginx is not a reverse proxy. It can be used as one, but that's not its main purpose.

Comment: But how can I host my page on a server? Is for school